# Sharepoint Fundation 2010, and Cmis comunication with the ECM

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Does SharePoint Foundation Server 2010 support CMIS communication with other enterprise content management systems?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 has a CMIS connector that lets you bring outside content into SharePoint as well as expose SharePoint to other CMIS capable systems.  You can read more on this on the TechNet website here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934619(v=office.14).aspx

**EDIT**: This is only supported on SharePoint Server 2010.  SharePoint Foundation 2010 has no such functionality.